# How to create a bi-input TPU model for images?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tpu

I want to convert my GPU model to TPU model. My GPU model takes two input image and has the same output for both images. I use custom data generator for this. There are two parallel networks; one for each input.

From this [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52582275/tf-data-with-multiple-inputs-outputs-in-keras/52688493#52688493), I tried to solve this but I failed.
Here is what I tried

```
dataset_12 = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((left_train_paths, right_train_paths))
dataset_label = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(train_labels) 
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.zip((dataset_12, dataset_label)).batch(2).repeat()
```

Problem I am facing is that I am unable to decode the bi-input images.
Here is the decoder function

```
def decode_image(filename, label=None, image_size=(IMG_SIZE_h, IMG_SIZE_w)):
    bits = tf.io.read_file(filename)
    image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(bits, channels=3)
    image = tf.cast(image, tf.float32) / 255.0
    image = tf.image.resize(image, image_size)
    
    #convert to numpy and do some cv2 staff mb?
    
    if label is None:
        return image
    else:
        return image, label
```

The issue is that I am unable to pass both images to the decoder function at the same time. How can I resolve this?

I also try to decode the image in following way

```
 def decode(img,image_size=(IMG_SIZE_h, IMG_SIZE_w)):
    bits = tf.io.read_file(img)
    image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(bits, channels=3)
    image = tf.cast(image, tf.float32) / 255.0
    image = tf.image.resize(image, image_size)
    return image
def decode_image(left, right,labels=None ):
    if labels is None:
        return decode(left),decode(right)
    else:
        return decode(left),decode(right),labels 
    
image=tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((left_train_paths,right_train_paths,train_labels ))
dataset=image.map(decode_image, num_parallel_calls=AUTO).repeat().shuffle(512).batch(BATCH_SIZE).prefetch(AUTO)
dataset
```

The output is of `dataset` variable is now as
`<PrefetchDataset shapes: ((None, 760, 760, 3), (None, 760, 760, 3), (None, 8)), types: (tf.float32, tf.float32, tf.int64)>`

How can I pass it to the model now?

**Model**

```
def get_model():
    
    left_tensor = Input(shape=(IMG_SIZE_h,IMG_SIZE_w,3))
    right_tensor = Input(shape=(IMG_SIZE_h,IMG_SIZE_w,3))

    left_model =  EfficientNetB3(input_shape =  (img_shape,img_shape,3), include_top = False, weights = 'imagenet',input_tensor=left_tensor)
    right_model = EfficientNetB3(input_shape =  (img_shape,img_shape,3), include_top = False, weights = 'imagenet',input_tensor=right_tensor)
    con = concatenate([left_model.output, right_model.output])
    GAP= GlobalAveragePooling2D()(con)
    out = Dense(8, activation = 'sigmoid')(GAP)
    model =Model(inputs=[left_input, right_input], outputs=out)

    return model
```

Comment: I understand that you already solved the problem of decoding the two images, isn't it? At least the dataset shapes looks okey. You mention that you want to feed to the model two batches of images at once, but we cannot help you unless you show your current model, or at least you model's input layer.

Comment: @Guillem I have updated the question, please check model

Comment: I think the problem is that `model.fit(dataset,....` is supposed two have one batch of training image and one batch of corresponding labels. But I have two batches of training data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a pretty elegant solution. I will explain step by step since may be a bit different of what you thought:

1. When decoding the images stack both images in a single tensor so the input tensor will be of shape [2, IMAGE_H, IMAGE_W, 3]

```py
def decode_single(im_path, image_size):
    bits = tf.io.read_file(im_path)
    image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(bits, channels=3)
    image = tf.cast(image, tf.float32) / 255.0
    image = tf.image.resize(image, image_size)
    return image

# Note that the image paths are packed in a tuple, and we unpack them inside the function
def decode(paths, label=None, image_size=(128, 128)):
    image_path1, image_path2 = paths
    im1 = decode_single(image_path1, image_size)
    im2 = decode_single(image_path2, image_size)
    images = tf.stack([im1, im2])

    if label is not None:
        return images, label

    return images
```

2. I declare the data pipeline so the paths are packed in a tuple.

```py
label_ds = ...
ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((left_paths, right_paths))
ds = tf.data.Dataset.zip((ds, label_ds)) # returns as ((im_path1, im_path2), label)) not (im_path1, im_path2, label)
ds = ds.map(decode).batch(4)
print(ds)
# Out: <BatchDataset shapes: ((None, 2, 128, 128, 3), ((None,),)), types: (tf.float32, (tf.int32,))>
```

3. Since we are feeding batches of two images (None, 2, 128, 128, 3). Declare the model with a single input of shape (2, HEIGHT, WIDTH, 3) and then we split the input in the two images:

```py
def get_model():
    input_layer = Input(shape=(2, IMAGE_H,IMAGE_W,3))
    # Split into two images
    right_image, left_image = Lambda(lambda x: tf.split(x, 2, axis=1))(input_layer)
    
    right_image = Reshape([IMAGE_H, IMAGE_W, 3])(right_image)
    left_image = Reshape([IMAGE_H, IMAGE_W, 3])(left_image)
    # Replace by EfficientNets
    left_model =  Conv2D(64, 3)(left_image)
    right_model = Conv2D(64, 3)(right_image)
    con = Concatenate(-1)([left_model, right_model])
    GAP = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(con)
    out = Dense(8, activation = 'sigmoid')(GAP)
    model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=out)

    return model
```

4. Finally compile and train the model as usual:

```py
model = get_model()
model.compile(...)
model.fit(ds, epochs=10)
```

Comment: just adding the lambda layer resolve the issue, and enclosing `decode(left),decode(right)` in list. thanks a lot