# Passing x_train as a list of numpy arrays to tf.data.Dataset is not working

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets

My problem is that x_train in tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(x_train, y_train) needs to be a list. When I use the following lines to pass [x1_train,x2_train] to tensorflow.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices, then I get error (x1_train, x2_train and y_train are numpy arrays):

```
Train=tensorflow.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(([x1_train,x2_train], y_train)).batch(batch_size)
```

Error:

```
Train=tensorflow.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(([x1_train,x2_train], y_train)).batch(batch_size)
return ops.EagerTensor(value, ctx.device_name, dtype)
ValueError: Can't convert non-rectangular Python sequence to Tensor.
```

What should I do?

Comment: Which line do you get this error in?

Comment: I have updated question

Comment: Actually I came across the exact same error today and my problem was that `x_train` in `tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(x_train, y_train)` needed to be a list, but with the information you provided I am not sure if this also applies to you. Could you provide some more information about your actual goal and what kind of data is included in `x1_train`, `x2_train` and `y_train`?

Comment: Yes. I also have the same problem. x1_train, x2_train and y_train are numpy arrays and I need to pass [x1_train,x2_train] because my model has two set of inputs (I pass one of them through some layers and then aggregate with second set of inputs). How did you solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the main goal is to feed data to a model having multiple input layers then the following might be helpful:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
import numpy as np

def _input_fn(n):
  x1_train = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], dtype=np.int64)
  x2_train = np.array([15, 25, 35, 45, 55, 65, 75, 85], dtype=np.int64)

  labels = np.array([40, 30, 20, 10, 80, 70, 50, 60], dtype=np.int64)

  dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(({"input_1": x1_train, "input_2": x2_train}, labels))
  dataset = dataset.batch(2, drop_remainder=True)
  dataset = dataset.repeat(n)
  return dataset

input1 = keras.layers.Input(shape=(1,), name='input_1')
input2 = keras.layers.Input(shape=(1,), name='input_2')

model = keras.models.Model(inputs=[input_1, input_2], outputs=output)
```

basically instead of passing a python list, pass a dictionary where the key indicates the layer's name to which the array will be fed to.

like in the above array `x1_train` will be fed to tensor `input1` whose name is **input_1**. Refered from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52582275/tf-data-with-multiple-inputs-outputs-in-keras)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How can I use .prefetch,.catch and .make_one_shot_iterator in your code? (I want to train on multiple GPUs)

Comment: @hsn15051, yes you can use

Comment: Could u please tell me in what order shall I use? (before dataset.repeat(n) or after dataset.repeat(n))

Comment: @hsn15051, putting the whole code here for training on mult-gpus will be out of scope for this question. Please ask a separate question for this, and also mention your tensorflow version. Also refer this video presentation once https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZnukSLKEw34&list=PLSSIxfENhg_0AWjXuH_wbqv25nTS_Wcow&index=4&t=1274s

Comment: I used tf.data with tfrecords. The sequence which I use for this is `list_files->shuffle->repeat->interleave->batch->map->cache->prefetch`

Answer (score 0):

If you have a dataframe with different types (float32, int and str) you have to create it manually.

Following the Pratik's syntax:

```
tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(({"input_1": np.asarray(var_float).astype(np.float32), "imput_2": np.asarray(var_int).astype(np.int), ...}, labels))
```