# Keras Model Training - Is it possible to pass an generator with 1 or more inputs

Tags: tensorflow, keras, input

I'm currently working on a Visual Question Answering subject.
I've made a model as follow :

```
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
input_3 (InputLayer)            [(None, 224, 224, 3) 0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
block1_conv1 (Conv2D)           (None, 224, 224, 64) 1792        input_3[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
block1_conv2 (Conv2D)           (None, 224, 224, 64) 36928       block1_conv1[0][0]               
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
block1_pool (MaxPooling2D)      (None, 112, 112, 64) 0           block1_conv2[0][0]               
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
block2_conv1 (Conv2D)           (None, 112, 112, 128 73856       block1_pool[0][0]                
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
block2_conv2 (Conv2D)           (None, 112, 112, 128 147584      block2_conv1[0][0]               
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
block2_pool (MaxPooling2D)      (None, 56, 56, 128)  0           block2_conv2[0][0]               
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
block3_conv1 (Conv2D)           (None, 56, 56, 256)  295168      block2_pool[0][0]                
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
block3_conv2 (Conv2D)           (None, 56, 56, 256)  590080      block3_conv1[0][0]               
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
block3_conv3 (Conv2D)           (None, 56, 56, 256)  590080      block3_conv2[0][0]               
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
block3_conv4 (Conv2D)           (None, 56, 56, 256)  590080      block3_conv3[0][0]               
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
block3_pool (MaxPooling2D)      (None, 28, 28, 256)  0           block3_conv4[0][0]               
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
block4_conv1 (Conv2D)           (None, 28, 28, 512)  1180160     block3_pool[0][0]                
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
block4_conv2 (Conv2D)           (None, 28, 28, 512)  2359808     block4_conv1[0][0]               
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
block4_conv3 (Conv2D)           (None, 28, 28, 512)  2359808     block4_conv2[0][0]               
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
block4_conv4 (Conv2D)           (None, 28, 28, 512)  2359808     block4_conv3[0][0]               
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
block4_pool (MaxPooling2D)      (None, 14, 14, 512)  0           block4_conv4[0][0]               
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
block5_conv1 (Conv2D)           (None, 14, 14, 512)  2359808     block4_pool[0][0]                
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
block5_conv2 (Conv2D)           (None, 14, 14, 512)  2359808     block5_conv1[0][0]               
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
block5_conv3 (Conv2D)           (None, 14, 14, 512)  2359808     block5_conv2[0][0]               
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
block5_conv4 (Conv2D)           (None, 14, 14, 512)  2359808     block5_conv3[0][0]               
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
block5_pool (MaxPooling2D)      (None, 7, 7, 512)    0           block5_conv4[0][0]               
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
flatten_1 (Flatten)             (None, 25088)        0           block5_pool[0][0]                
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
input_4 (InputLayer)            [(None, 20)]         0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
repeat_vector_1 (RepeatVector)  (None, 20, 25088)    0           flatten_1[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
embedding_1 (Embedding)         (None, 20, 50)       901900      input_4[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate_1 (Concatenate)     (None, 20, 25138)    0           repeat_vector_1[0][0]            
                                                                 embedding_1[0][0]                
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
bidirectional_1 (Bidirectional) (None, 20, 50)       5032800     concatenate_1[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
global_max_pooling1d_1 (GlobalM (None, 50)           0           bidirectional_1[0][0]            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)                 (None, 18037)        919887      global_max_pooling1d_1[0][0]     
==================================================================================================
```

You can find the original paper on VQA, here : http://arxiv.org/pdf/1512.02167.pdf

To sum up I have a Model with 2 inputs

- a pre-trained VGG19 that take images
- and an embedded layer that take tokenized question.

As output we have a Bidirectional LSTM with a final Dense layer that give the answer to the question.

The training data is at follow :

```
          img_path                              question                         answer
103 train2014/COCO_train2014_000000262171.jpg   How many people are on the boat?    5   
104 train2014/COCO_train2014_000000262171.jpg   What color are the leaves?  green
105 train2014/COCO_train2014_000000262171.jpg   What type of watercraft is that?    raft    
131 train2014/COCO_train2014_000000262180.jpg   What is the fruit?  banana
132 train2014/COCO_train2014_000000262180.jpg   Is this a good dessert?
```

My question is this one : **I can't charge all the images in memory, I will like to know if it is possible to fit the model using a generator to generate the image on the fly + the tokenize question ?**

I would like to do something like :

```
h = model_VQA.fit([X_train_img_generator, X_train_question], y_train_answer, epochs = 15, batch_size = 32)
```

where : **X_train_question** are the tokenized questions and **X_train_img_generator** the image generator.

--> But it doesn't work, is there a way to handle this properly ?

---------- Edit June 02 2021

Ok I've now update the answer to my problem and also correct some issu regarding input image size is now 480x640x3

```
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
input_8 (InputLayer)            [(None, 480, 640, 3) 0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
block1_conv1 (Conv2D)           (None, 480, 640, 64) 1792        input_8[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
block1_conv2 (Conv2D)           (None, 480, 640, 64) 36928       block1_conv1[0][0]               
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
block1_pool (MaxPooling2D)      (None, 240, 320, 64) 0           block1_conv2[0][0]               
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
block2_conv1 (Conv2D)           (None, 240, 320, 128 73856       block1_pool[0][0]                
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
block2_conv2 (Conv2D)           (None, 240, 320, 128 147584      block2_conv1[0][0]               
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
block2_pool (MaxPooling2D)      (None, 120, 160, 128 0           block2_conv2[0][0]               
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
block3_conv1 (Conv2D)           (None, 120, 160, 256 295168      block2_pool[0][0]                
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
block3_conv2 (Conv2D)           (None, 120, 160, 256 590080      block3_conv1[0][0]               
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
block3_conv3 (Conv2D)           (None, 120, 160, 256 590080      block3_conv2[0][0]               
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
block3_conv4 (Conv2D)           (None, 120, 160, 256 590080      block3_conv3[0][0]               
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
block3_pool (MaxPooling2D)      (None, 60, 80, 256)  0           block3_conv4[0][0]               
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
block4_conv1 (Conv2D)           (None, 60, 80, 512)  1180160     block3_pool[0][0]                
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
block4_conv2 (Conv2D)           (None, 60, 80, 512)  2359808     block4_conv1[0][0]               
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
block4_conv3 (Conv2D)           (None, 60, 80, 512)  2359808     block4_conv2[0][0]               
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
block4_conv4 (Conv2D)           (None, 60, 80, 512)  2359808     block4_conv3[0][0]               
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
block4_pool (MaxPooling2D)      (None, 30, 40, 512)  0           block4_conv4[0][0]               
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
block5_conv1 (Conv2D)           (None, 30, 40, 512)  2359808     block4_pool[0][0]                
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
block5_conv2 (Conv2D)           (None, 30, 40, 512)  2359808     block5_conv1[0][0]               
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
block5_conv3 (Conv2D)           (None, 30, 40, 512)  2359808     block5_conv2[0][0]               
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
block5_conv4 (Conv2D)           (None, 30, 40, 512)  2359808     block5_conv3[0][0]               
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
block5_pool (MaxPooling2D)      (None, 15, 20, 512)  0           block5_conv4[0][0]               
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
flatten_7 (Flatten)             (None, 153600)       0           block5_pool[0][0]                
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
input_quest (InputLayer)        [(None, None)]       0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
repeat_vector_7 (RepeatVector)  (None, 20, 153600)   0           flatten_7[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
embedding_7 (Embedding)         (None, 20, 50)     540700      input_quest[0][0]                
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate_7 (Concatenate)     (None, 20, 153650)   0           repeat_vector_7[0][0]            
                                                                 embedding_7[0][0]                
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
bidirectional_7 (Bidirectional) (None, 20, 22)       13522256    concatenate_7[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
global_max_pooling1d_7 (GlobalM (None, 22)           0           bidirectional_7[0][0]            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_7 (Dense)                 (None, 7465)         171695      global_max_pooling1d_7[0][0]     
==================================================================================================
```

And the dataset as :

```
def load(file_path):

    img = tf.io.read_file(file_path)
    img = tf.image.decode_png(img, channels=3)
    img = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(img, tf.float32)
    img = preprocess_input(img)

    #img = tf.image.resize(img, size=(224, 224))
    img /= 255.
    img = tf.expand_dims(img, axis = 0)

    return img

x1 = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(X_img_train).map(lambda xx: load(xx))
x2 = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(X_train_rnn_pad)
y = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(answer_tr)
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.zip(((x1, x2), y))


h = model_VQA.fit(x = dataset, batch_size = 32, shuffle = True, epochs = 15)
```

but I get the following error :

```
ValueError: Dimension 0 in both shapes must be equal, but are 1 and 20. Shapes are [1,20] and [20,1]. for '{{node model_8/concatenate_7/concat}} = ConcatV2[N=2, T=DT_FLOAT, Tidx=DT_INT32](model_8/repeat_vector_7/Tile, model_8/embedding_7/embedding_lookup/Identity_1, model_8/concatenate_7/concat/axis)' with input shapes: [1,20,153600], [20,1,50], [] and with computed input tensors: input[2] = <2>.
```

I guess it has to do with the input shape for the Embedding part, but I don't what I missing

My Inputs data shape are

X_train_rnn_pad = (53607,20),
and
answer_tr = (53607, 7465)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you should use something like the [`tf.data.Datasets`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset) API

if you have a 2 input model, you will do something like this:

```
x = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((img_path_array, questions_array))
y = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(answer_array)
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.zip((x, y)).shuffle(50)
```

After that, you can use the [.map method](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#map) to load your images and also apply data augmentation if you want.

Then for fitting you simply do:

```
h = model.fit(dataset)
```

Using this API avoids loading images in memory.

Comment: I see I give it a try !

Comment: Its a moment since I look into Dataset, but I have a really hard time to understand how I handle all this. I don't understand how you map to a generator

Comment: [Here's a complete example in the answers] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63636427/how-to-load-images-by-their-paths-in-dataframe-columns-for-dual-input-using-data). I recommend you learn how to use it, It may take some time at first. It is a powerful tool and helps with scalability.

Comment: Ok I gonna try my best to understand it. Let you know my progress

Comment: I still have an issu : ValueError: Dimension 0 in both shapes must be equal, but are 1 and 20. Shapes are [1,20] and [20,1]. for '{{node model_8/concatenate_7/concat}} = ConcatV2[N=2, T=DT_FLOAT, Tidx=DT_INT32](model_8/repeat_vector_7/Tile, model_8/embedding_7/embedding_lookup/Identity_1, model_8/concatenate_7/concat/axis)' with input shapes: [1,20,153600], [20,1,50], [] and with computed input tensors: input[2] = <2>.                                                              I guess it's due to inputs but can't figure out why ... [see edit]